# How can I work around Argo output parameter size limit?

Tags: scalability, argo-workflows

I have an Argo workflow that loops over a JSON array. When the list gets too large, I get an error like this:

```
time="some-time" level=fatal msg="Pod \"some-pod-name\" is invalid: metadata.annotations: Too long: must have at most 262144 characters"
```

Or, [in newer versions of Argo](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/issues/765):

```
Output is larger than the maximum allowed size of 256 kB, only the last 256 kB were saved
```

How can I loop over this large JSON array without hitting the size limit?

My workflow looks a bit like this, but with a bigger JSON array:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: loops-sequence-
spec:
  entrypoint: loops-sequence
  templates:
  - name: loops-sequence
    steps:
    - - name: get-items
        template: get-items
    - - name: sequence-param
        template: echo
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: item
            value: "{{item}}"
        withParam: "{{steps.get-items.outputs.parameters.items}}"
  - name: get-items
    container:
      image: alpine:latest
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
      args: ["echo '[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]' > /tmp/items"]
    outputs:
      parameters:
      - name: items
        valueFrom:
          path: /tmp/items
  - name: echo
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: item
    container:
      image: stedolan/jq:latest
      command: [echo, "{{inputs.parameters.item}}"]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of writing the JSON array to an output parameter, write it to an artifact and its length to an output parameter. Then you can use `withSequence` to loop over the array indexes and retrieve the corresponding item from the JSON artifact.

Here's an example with a hard-coded JSON array and item count. Your `get-items` step will certainly be more sophisticated.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: loops-sequence-
spec:
  entrypoint: loops-sequence
  templates:
  - name: loops-sequence
    steps:
    - - name: get-items
        template: get-items
    - - name: sequence-param
        template: echo
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: index
            value: "{{item}}"
          artifacts:
          - name: items
            from: "{{steps.get-items.outputs.artifacts.items}}"
        withSequence:
          count: "{{steps.get-items.outputs.parameters.count}}"
  - name: get-items
    container:
      image: alpine:latest
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
      args: ["echo '[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]' > /tmp/items && echo '3' > /tmp/count"]
    outputs:
      artifacts:
      - name: items
        path: /tmp/items
      parameters:
      - name: count
        valueFrom:
          path: /tmp/count
  - name: echo
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: index
      artifacts:
      - name: items
        path: /tmp/items
    container:
      image: stedolan/jq:latest
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["cat /tmp/items | jq '.[{{inputs.parameters.index}}]'"]
```