# Argo workflows big stdout output to input file

Tags: argo-workflows

---

I'm trying to use the `stdout` from a step as file input from another step.

Since the output is pretty big, I'm getting the error `argument list too long`.

```
...
spec:
  templates:
  - name: main
    steps:
    - - name: big-output
...
    - - name: print
        template: head-query
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: query-result
            raw:
              data: "{{steps.big-output.outputs.result}}"
  - name: head-query
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: query-result
        path: /input/query.txt
        raw:
          data: "{{inputs.parameters.query-result}}"
    container:
      image: alpine
      command: [head]
      args:
      - /input/query.txt
```

What is the proper way to put the `stdout` in a file? Is there some way to avoid modifying the step with the big output?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work, as long as the output doesn't exceed the [256kb limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62537126/684776) for output parameters.

The Workflow as it is written is invalid, because `raw` is meant to be used with artifacts rather than parameters.

If you were to run `argo lint` you would get an error like this:

```
   ✖ in "big-parameter-" (Workflow): json: unknown field "path"

✖ 1 linting errors found!
```

Modifying the Workflow manifest to use artifacts instead of parameters should allow it to work.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: big-parameter-
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
    - name: main
      steps:
        - - name: big-output
            template: big-output
        - - name: print
            template: head-query
            arguments:
              artifacts:
                - name: query-result
                  raw:
                    data: "{{steps.big-output.outputs.result}}"
    - name: big-output
      script:
        image: alpine
        command:
          - sh
        source: |
          echo "pretend this is really big"
    - name: head-query
      inputs:
        artifacts:
          - name: query-result
            path: /input/query.txt
      container:
        image: alpine
        command: [head]
        args:
          - /input/query.txt
```

Comment: I'm still getting the `argument list too long` error. After checking the generated yaml in the cluster, I can see that it's adding the template as an environment variable `ARGO_TEMPLATE` with the value of the parameter in it; making it huge.

I'm guessing there is no way to treat the output purely as a file.